# Script directory path regardless of current/working directory

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to get the script directory regardless of change in current directory that occurred during script execution.

```sh
echo $(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
cd /tmp
echo $(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
```

```
/home/user/test
/tmp
```

In the example above, I need `/home/user/test` both times, without storing it to a variable.

Comment: Why not use a variable?

Comment: Yes, that would be one method, and I use it now, but perhaps there is another way.

Comment: That's actually difficult to do in all cases; see ["How can I get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-can-i-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itsel) and [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job in your script:

```
dir="$(readlink /proc/$PPID/cwd)"
```

Comment: This only works if the script was run from the same directory the script itself is in, *and* it hasn't been backgrounded and the parent process changed directories, *and* you're on a system that has /proc.

Comment: Indeed, the script directory resolves to the user's home when launched from cron

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thank you for the hints. Yes, the scope is limited.